# Socket.io-client fires duplicate 'reconnect_failed' event

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

It seems like **reconnect_failed** event is fired twice in socket.io-client. I have tried setting different values for *reconnectionAttempts*, but even if it is 1, 2 or 3 it always fire the event twice.

To reproduce scenario, run at client side

```
var opts = { reconnection: true, reconnectionAttempts: 3, reconnectionDelay: 500}
var socket = io.connect(opts)
socket.on('reconnect_failed', function() {
    console.log("Reconnect failed")
})
```

While running kill node server (CTRL+C) and you will get following output in Developer tools console:

```
Reconnect failed 
Reconnect failed
```

Im using socket.io 1.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in next version.

See reply on Github: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/issues/705